# efficiently fill a tensor in numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy array `X` of size `(n, m)` and of type `np.uint8` (so it only contains values in `[0, 255]`). I also have a mapping `f` from `[0, 255]` to `[0, 3]`.

I want to create an array `Y` of shape `(4, n, m)` such that `y_{k, i, j} = 1 if k == f(x_{i, j})` and 0 otherwise. For now, I do it like this:

```
Y = np.zeros((4, n, m))
for i in range(256):
  Y[f(i), X == i] = 1
```

But this is super slow, and I'm not able to find a more efficient way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share the implementation of func `f`?

Comment: Mmm it's not easy to share because it's a very problem specific function, but it's a function that takes no time to execute, and nothing in it could be used to make the whole process faster. It could be something like this:
def f(x): v[x]
where v = np.random.randint(4, size=(256,))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `f` could operate on all iterating values in one-go, you can use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
Yout = (f(X) == np.arange(4)[:,None,None]).astype(int)
```

Runtime test and verification -

```
In [35]: def original_app(X,n,m):
    ...:     Y = np.zeros((4, n, m))
    ...:     for i in range(256):
    ...:         Y[f(i), X == i] = 1
    ...:     return Y
    ...: 

In [36]: # Setup Inputs
    ...: n,m = 2000,2000
    ...: X = np.random.randint(0,255,(n,m)).astype('uint8')
    ...: v = np.random.randint(4, size=(256,))
    ...: def f(x): 
    ...:     return v[x]
    ...: 

In [37]: Y = original_app(X,n,m)
    ...: Yout = (f(X) == np.arange(4)[:,None,None]).astype(int)
    ...: 

In [38]: np.allclose(Yout,Y)  # Verify
Out[38]: True

In [39]: %timeit original_app(X,n,m)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.77 s per loop

In [40]: %timeit (f(X) == np.arange(4)[:,None,None]).astype(int)
10 loops, best of 3: 74.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

The mix of scalar indexing and boolean appears to be hurting your speed:

```
In [706]: %%timeit
     ...: Y=np.zeros((4,3,4))
     ...: for i in range(256):
     ...:   Y[f(i), X==i]+=1
     ...: 

100 loops, best of 3: 12.5 ms per loop

In [722]: %%timeit
     ...: Y=np.zeros((4,3,4))
     ...: for i in range(256):
     ...:     I,J=np.where(X==i)
     ...:     Y[f(i),I,J] = 1
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.55 ms per loop
```

This is for

```
X=np.arange(12,dtype=np.uint8).reshape(3,4)
def f(i):
    return i%4
```

In this case, the `f(i)` is not a major time consumer:

```
In [718]: timeit K=[f(i) for i in range(256)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 120 µs per loop
```

but getting the `X==i` indexes is slow

```
In [720]: timeit K=[X==i for i in range(256)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop
In [721]: timeit K=[np.where(X==i) for i in range(256)]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.73 ms per loop
```

We need to rethink the `X==i` part of the mapping, rather than the `f(i)` part.

=====================

Flattening the last 2 dimensions helps;

```
In [780]: %%timeit 
     ...: X1=X.ravel()
     ...: Y=np.zeros((4,12))
     ...: for i in range(256):
     ...:     Y[f(i),X1==i]=1
     ...: Y.shape=(4,3,4)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.16 ms per loop
```

Comment: That surprises me - does boolean indexing not translate to `nonzero` under the hood anyway? Your second example has dropped a `+=`

Comment: Tested on my PC - most of your time difference you're observing in that first part is due to that `=` vs `+=` typo, sadly

Comment: You are right.  I was testing the `+=` at one point because I was thinking of the case where an unbuffered `add.at` would required (duplicate values in `X`).

Comment: Working with `X.ravel()` helps.